# Sql Server 2005, Xml types, and ODBC?

Tags: sql-server, odbc

Can a Sql 2005 database that uses the xml type be accessed with ODBC?

Answer (score 1):

I believe XML datatypes will be, pretty much, handled as character data types...

Certainly, the OpenLink ODBC driver returns XML data types, locally, as SQL_LONGVARCHAR.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is true for all ODBC drivers connecting to SQL Server 2005, but DataDirect does claim to support pretty much all SQL Server 2005 and even most of the new SQL Server 2008 features. See their listing [here](http://www.datadirect.com/products/odbc/odbc-sqlserver/index.ssp).

Ah, and [here's Microsoft comment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130828(SQL.90).aspx) on it:

*If you are developing a COM-based application and need to access the new features of SQL Server 2005, you should use SQL Native Client. If you don't need access to the new features of SQL Server 2005, you can continue to use Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC).*

So I guess, if you use the SQL Native Client ODBC driver, you should be able to use the XML data type.

Marc

Answer (score 0):

This's supported in the sql server's native client odbc driver with the new SQL_SS_XML type.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms131375%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx